# Getting error when updating blog post with tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Hello I just started with Ruby on Rails and its a very cool language to work with.. But after finishing the tutorial I encounter an error that I don't really understand since I followed the getting started tut on rubyonrails.org

Here is the code that I think gives the problem

```
<%= form.fields_for :tags do |tag_form| %>
<div class="field">
  <%= tag_form.label :name, 'Tag:' %>
  <%= tag_form.text_field :name %>
</div>
<% unless tag_form.object.nil? || tag_form.object.new_record? %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= tag_form.label :_destroy, 'Remove:' %>
    <%= tag_form.check_box :_destroy %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The error is

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The correct thing here to do is:

Modify your Post class and add tag attributes

```
attr_accessible :content, :name, :title, :tags_attributes
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you add an association or new field to your model, if you're using `attr_accessible`, you'll also want to add that into your model. `attr_accessible` is a method to allow these fields to be modified through mass assignment. For example, you would not want to include an admin boolean from your user model in your `attr_accessible` since that would allow users to inject and promote themselves to an admin status. This is similar to the issue that Github had a few months ago.

In your case, you would want to add `:tag_attributes` to your `attr_accessible` line in your Post model.